# What does it mean if some files in TortoiseSVN are marked "deleted" and others "deleted (+)" with a plus sign?

Tags: file, svn, tortoisesvn, delete-file

I'm about to do a commit in TortoiseSVN involving rearranging a lot of files and directories. On the "commit" window, there are several files whose text status is "deleted" or "added" but others whose text status is "deleted (+)" or "added (+)". What does the (+) mean?

(It's quite difficult to Google for a plus sign, and the word "plus" turns up lots of hits about the blue overlay icon meaning "added")

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The "+" means that TortoiseSVN was able to figure out the item's history, and has added the history metadata to this commit. For instance, say you rename a file from `a` to `b`. If you see the `(+)`, Tortoise knows that you didn't really delete a file called `a` and make a file called `b`, and has determined that a rename took place.

That's good, because it means you can trace the history of `b` backwards to the point where it used to be `a`. Otherwise, you'd hit a dead end, and it would look like `b` sprang out of nowhere in the history. You can mouseover these entries and see more details about where they came from.

Comment: I don't see anything happening when I mouseover these files, but I can right-click on them and select "show logs" which does the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Deleted(+) is used to indicate that the file isn't really gone, it's just been renamed, and there is an associated added(+) that represents the new file.

Comment: for me it is showing A+ for the root directory httpdocs. So this will affect the commits in anyway  ?