# What does normal(+) status in svn denotes?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using tortoise svn versioning tool and merged code changes from one branch to another.
now i want to commit my changes in merged branch.

for some files i am getting status as `normal(+)`

can anyone tell what this status denotes?

i'm getting status as shown in below picture

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The plus sign tells you that a file or folder has been scheduled to be added to version control.

**Edit for updated question**:

"The (+) means that TortoiseSVN was able to figure out the item's history, and has added the history metadata to this commit." Meaning you can trace the state of the file in which it used to exist, hence version control. Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073639/what-does-it-mean-if-some-files-in-tortoisesvn-are-marked-deleted-and-others) post.

[More info](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html) on status.

Comment: what is the difference between added(+) and normal(+)?

Comment: Added means it is scheduled to be added to version control and normal means it is a fresh, checked-out working copy. The link I provided on the bottom explains the different status in subversion.

Comment: I don't think the previous answer was correct on added(+) vs normal(+). If I merge a folder from one branch to another, the folder's status is "added (+)" but the children files of that folder have a status of "normal (+)". But they are all being added just as their parent folder is being added. So why does SVN use added vs normal?

Answer (score 5):

Dan's answer is correct. And to add information for Developer Webs' question:

> If I merge a folder from one branch to another, the folder's status is
>   "added (+)" but the children files of that folder have a status of
>   "normal (+)". But they are all being added just as their parent folder
>   is being added. So why does SVN use added vs normal?

The files with `normal(+)` will be added to the commit, but you don't need to check it for committing. As the parent folder has an `added(+)` status, it will be included recursively.
Also, no transfer from your local copy to the server will be done, as **the file is already on the server**.

Also, there is a `modified(+)` status: it means that after the merge brought the file you made some changes to it. So, it must be checked to be committed with this new changes.

The `deleted(+)` status means that the file was brought from the merge but you later deleted it. It must be commited.